# JQuery hover last item repeating

Tags: jquery

My rollover social icons are not working properly. Upon page load, they are all loading properly. But upon rollover, they are all rolling over with the very last hover image (email icon). Can someone tell me where I've gone wrong in the JQuery? Also, I could not paste my entire JQuery code here - it was cutting me off. So I know something is very wrong. What I'm doing is just repeating the JQuery below 4 times and changing out the url's.

```
jQuery('#fsml_ffmain > a.fsml_fflink:nth-child(n) > img.fsml_fficon').hover(
function () {
    jQuery(this).attr('src', 'http://drlindatucker.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/facebook-hover-black-brown.png');
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).attr('src','http://drlindatucker.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/facebook-black-brown.png');
}
```

Comment: Do you also replace `(n)` with an actual number?

Comment: The problem sounds like you're not using specific enough selectors, so you're binding all the icons to the same hover handlers.

Comment: No, I'm not replacing the (n). That must be the problem.

Comment: Yeah, the argument to `:nth-child()` has to be a literal number, variables aren't expanded. If you want to use a variable, you have to use concatenation.

Comment: So if I have 4 icons, I can use 1 2 3 4 ?

Comment: of course. What else would you use? Or you could give them distinctive classes, rather than referring to them by position.